# Why i can't use generic type with lamba expression?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, generic-list

Why i can't use the following lambda inside a method? Under what circumstances is allowed to use generic types?

For example i know that i can use generics inside a class:

```
//Valid
public class GenericList<T>
{
    void Add(T input) { }
}
```

but i can't in the following code:

```
 //Not valid
 private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Edit:
     //As you can guess this is a timer event and Action is called
     //only in this scope but possibly more than one time
     //that's why i though to make it Action method. 

     //In the following line `Τ` is not recognized...
     Action<List<T>, List<T>> syncLists = (l1, l2) => { ... };
 }
```

<sup>** I don't think it's framework specific but just in case i use 3.5</sup>

Comment: Is `T` defined in outer class definition?

Comment: What would you be trying to accomplish? What type is `T` supposed to represent in your second code example? With generics, eventually you have to specify the types. Where would the types for `T` be specified in your code?

Comment: i need to define a small function only inside `Timer` scope. `T` could be whatever class since i want a generic type. Probably i could use `dynamic` but is not preferable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to expose the TypeParameter in the method signature like this:

```
private void Timer1_Tick<T>(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Action<List<T>, List<T>> syncLists = (l1, l2) => { ... };
 }
```

Otherwise there is no way for the client to specify how the method should behave, and what type is to be acted upon.

An alternative technique, more appropriate in some circumstances, would be to expose the Type Parameter in the class signature thus:

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Action<List<T>, List<T>> syncLists = (l1, l2) => { ... };
     }
}
```

Comment: Method seems like event handler, so I don't think OP can make it generic.

Comment: @2kay: It seems unusual, but it is hard to make accurate general statements about business requirements in such a broad arena.

Comment: What can i achieve by doing that? My idea was to use a local scope function inside the timer to avoid repetition. The problem is i want a List of generic types and i prefer not to use dynamic. Thanks for your response

Comment: @JorgeCode: Your business requirement remains quite vague. Any more specific assistance will require that you provide a clearer business case, probably with one or two specific examples of intended usage.